# git. отвалилась голова. Я не заметил и сделал коммиты в безымянную ветку. Как вернуть?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Несколько раз откатывал состояние рабочей области к разным коммитам. Потом вернулся к самому свежему. Но так как делал это не в консоли, то не заметил, что вернулся не к ветке master, а к её коммиту по хешу. В итоге HEAD отвалился. Я не заметил, что гит предупредил:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state
```

и закоммитил несколько раз. Теперь заметил и у меня вот такая ситуация:

```
$ git log
commit 875a30059dcba645438a23dd466451fd0405d894 (HEAD)
  
commit d26a0d8845ac72b125c47c3dfb49b289df6bc893
    
commit 27ce01b5b84b5c5eeeb20a13f154134e70dcaa4c (master)
```

При попытке вернуться в мастер, последние два коммита пропадают. Как мне их вернуть внутрь ветки?
P.S. Не пушил. Ни каких других веток в этом репо нет.

Comment: Еще вариант - перенести коммиты по одному через `git cherry-pick`. А чтобы посмотреть что вы там делали (куда переключались, куда коммитили), `git reflog`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем случае самое простое

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff 875a30059dcba645438a23dd466451fd0405d894
```

Answer (score 0):

Часа 4 изучал разные способы решения. Но остановился на ручном передвижении указателя ветки master к нужному коммиту (это работает если предварительно не шатать репозиторий разными командами по переписыванию истории).

Для этого я открыл файл .git\refs\heads\master и заменил хеш текущего коммита на хеш самого свежего (в моём случае 27ce01b на 875a300) и моментально указатель мастера переместился. Теперь и master и HEAD указывают на один коммит, но башка ещё оторвана. Однако все коммиты и файлы на месте. Теперь достаточно сделать чекаут в мастер из консоли и репозиторий в порядке!
Возможно это опасно, но просто и понятно. Рекомендую перед экспериментами с локальным репозиторием скопировать его в другую папку.

Comment: Не нужно лазить в папку.git руками. Это чревато разоюломаным репозиторием

Comment: Да, согласен. Однако все мои попытки загуглить или понять читая доки не привели меня к тому ответу, который предложили вы. Большое спасибо.